# risks using dynamic-dns for selfhosted webservice

Tags: dynamic, dns, spoofing

I'm running a small self-hosted webserver using Apache and just PHP, HTML and CSS to
supply some PDF-documents to my customers. One of them now noted there could be "certain" risks using dynamic-DNS for my server. What could these risks for my customers be?
Thanks

I found this:
https://www.akamai.com/blog/security-research/spoofing-dns-by-abusing-dhcp

or are there possibly other risks and how can they be avoided?